# Convert List of Cats Effect IO to IO

Tags: scala

With Futures, If I have a list of Futures. I can convert them into a single future by doing `Future.sequence`. but on the cats.effect.IO there is no `IO.sequence` method.

So if I have a `List[IO[Long]]` how do I convert it into `IO[List[Long]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that what are you looking for?:

```
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.parallel._

val listIo : List[IO[Long]] = ???

listIo.parSequence
```

Comment: Which does not work without providing implicit Parallel

`implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IOContextShift(ExecutionContext.global)`